# Will pytorch performs correctly with python calculate codes in net?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

Take the fake codes below as an example:

```
class():
    def forward(input):
        x = some_torch_layers(input)
        x = some_torch_layers(x)
        ...
        x = sum(x) # or numpy or other operations
        x = some_torch_layers(x)
        return x
```

Will the pytorch net operates well? Especially, while the `sum(x)` performs well in the backward process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**
No.

In order for PyTorch to "perform well" it needs to propagate gradients through the net. PyTorch doesn't (and can't) know how to differentiate an arbtrary numpy code, it can only propagate gradients through PyTorch tensor operations.
In your examples the gradients will stop at the numpy `sum` so only the top-most torch layers will be trained (layers between numpy operation and the `criterion`), The other layers (between input and numpy operation) will have zero gradient and therefore their parameters will remain fixed throughout the training.

Comment: Will python operations with multiple losses perform well if I get multiple losses?

Comment: @zhkai I don't understand your question. If you are using operators such as `+` /`-` etc. torch knows how to deal with them and propagate gradients through them. as long as you do not convert your data from `torch.tensors` to `np.arrays` you should be okay.

Comment: Taking loss weight as an expample, can I just do `loss *= 0.1` to reduce the weight? Or `loss = -loss` to make parameters update oppositely?

Comment: @zhkai should be okay